# Crawler component in degraded state following index reset

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

**Problem**

Due to database storage issue, we had to reset index from GUI but got a timeout error. We then ran cmdlet to reset it.

Once we did that, the search application's administration status read "Paused for:External request, Index reset". When we tried to resume the search service application, we had no luck.

We then again ran index reset (after reading the article: https://sharepointthoughtssite.wordpress.com/2016/12/26/sharepoint-2013-on-prem-reset-index-stuck-resolution/)

That did not help.

As a side note, the crawler component in our topology is in uninitialized yellow state. We also notice that the search 15 service is in "starting" status in central administration. However, we are able to start and stop it successfully from services.msc

We would prefer to get the search service application to resume without redoing search service application.

**Things we have tried so far:**

Solution 1: Stopped admin and timer service. Cleared config cache. Started admin and timer service.

Solution 2: Unprovision and provision stuck search service on problematic server. Got below decryption error. Picture attached.
Error during decryption. System error code 0

Solution 3: Restarted Search Host Controller and Search 15 service from services.msc. They start fine but topology does not reflect it.

Solution 4: Resume search service application from Central Admin.

Solution 5: Ran PSConfig multiple times along with rebooting entire farm.

Solution 6: Tried replacing problematic component via cloning method but got below error:
Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology : Topology modification is not possible.
SearchServiceApplication 'Search Service Application' is paused for with
reason(s) other than Index Repartitioning.
At line:1 char:1 Set-SPEnterpriseSearchTopology -identity $clone

[image: administrative status]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you expand on what you mean by "database storage issue"? Could the search service application databases be corrupt?

Comment: @CallumCrowley we modified AAMs and some of the content was unreachable by the crawl and that filled up the database storage pretty fast. We were forced to do index reset to free up some of the space.

Comment: Did you do the index reset/changes while the search service was crawling? My experience is that major changes during a crawl can degrade the search service application.

Comment: we might have, unfortunately. are there any solutions to resuming search service application? we hate going down the path of rebuilding service application.

Comment: Maybe you can try to start, pause, resume, or stop a crawl for a content source from the site Central Administration.